# LINKED LIST- função intersecção

Tags: c, lista

Estou tendo dificuldade em fazer uma função intersecção entre duas listas encadeadas.

O código abaixo tem a função que estou fazendo, mas não está funcionando:

```
node* analysis(node* head_a, node* head_b){
   node* res;
   res->next = NULL;
   
   while(head_a != NULL){
       while(head_b != NULL){
           if(head_a->data == head_b->data) res = add(res, head_b->data);
           
           head_b = head_b->next;
       }
       head_a = head_a->next;
   }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: desculpa a pergunta, não sei estruturar a pergunta

Comment: Pode começar colocando o código suficiente para entendermos, esse `add()` não sabemos como se comporta sem o código (precisa ser um [mcve]). Também pode descrever o algoritmo que acha que faz funcionar a intersecção, qual seria o comportamento esperado (em detalhes) e o que não está acontecendo que vocẽ esperava que acontecesse (o problema pontual). Isso tudo tornaria a pergunta mais útil de maneira geral, que é o objetivo do site.

Comment: "node* add(node* head, int data){
    node* new_node;
    new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->next = head;
    new_node->data = data;
    return new_node;
}"

Comment: poste o programa inteiro, algo compilavel